# ConsumerRebalanceFailedException with the kafka-console-consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I've just installed kafka 0.9.0.1, and I'm getting the following error when launching the kafka-console-consumer:

```
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic myrandomtesttopic --from-beginning
[2016-03-30 15:46:17,568] ERROR Unknown error when running consumer:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$)
kafka.common.ConsumerRebalanceFailedException: console-consumer-84710_stg02-1459349168698-425dcf53 can't rebalance after 4 retries
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener.syncedRebalance(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:660)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.kafka$consumer$ZookeeperConsumerConnector$$reinitializeConsumer(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:967)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$WildcardStreamsHandler.<init>(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:1001)
at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreamsByFilter(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:163)
at kafka.consumer.OldConsumer.<init>(BaseConsumer.scala:75)
at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.run(ConsoleConsumer.scala:63)
at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:47)
at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
```

On `logs/zookeeper.out` there's only:

```
[2016-03-30 15:46:17,902] WARN caught end of stream exception (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x153c7e67216000e, likely client has closed socket
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-03-30 15:46:17,903] INFO Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:8857 which had sessionid 0x153c7e67216000e (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
[...]
```

Any idea what this may be about? :-\

Comment: Have you verified your broker is up and running?

Comment: Yes, I did make sure it was running :-)

Comment: Can you do `kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic myrandomtesttopic --zookeeper localhost:2181`

Comment: i have same issue, and im not able to read the data from kafka topics facing the same error on the consumer side

Comment: Were you able to find what caused it?